# Is there any web panel available out there that can start and stop a custom script/command I use to start/stop/update processes?

Tags: shell-script, python, php, java, webmin

I've read some other similar posts but not found exactly what I'm looking for, Webmin is a good start but can it handle actual scripts or just stop processes? I would like something that can just run a command or script.

I'm fine trying to attempt to develop a module for a panel that has that capability to make it work with what I'm looking for but if there is something already made then I'd rather do that instead.

Another option would be to make something with a language such as python to connect to the server and have an interface backed with python to remotely execute scripts/commands.

Any and all ideas on how I could go about this is appreciated, the goal is to have an interface that I can have some users click a button or two to manage some processes so they don't need to log in into the server directly via ssh and potentially mess up stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found what I'd call a panel for this but I've been able to use buttons with PHP to run scripts on Linux webservers following the examples here:

[Run a shell script with an html button | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235785/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bugy/script-server

This. Didn't use it, but looks interesting.

Comment: I use it and it's awesome